# Find the natural number $k <117$ such that $2^{117}\equiv k\pmod{117}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the natural number $k <117$ such that $2^{117}\equiv k \pmod {117}$.

I know $117$ is the product of $3$ and $37$.

$2^{117}\equiv 2 \pmod 3$
$2^{117}\equiv 31 \pmod {37}$.
But $2^{117}\equiv  44 \pmod {117}$.

I can't seem to understand how to get $44$. Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: well, $117 \neq 3 \cdot 37$, but it *is* $3 \cdot 39$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the chinese remainder theorem

$$2^{117}\equiv \ 2^3 = 8 \ (\ mod\ 9)$$

$$2^{117}\equiv \ 2^9 \equiv 5\ (\ mod\ 13\ )$$

Take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Remark that $8^4=4096=35\cdot117+1$ Hence $2^{117}=2^{3\cdot39}=8^{39}=8^{4\cdot9+3}\equiv(1)^9\cdot8^3$(mod$\space 117)$

Therefore $2^{117}\equiv(1)^9\cdot  512$ (mod$\space 117)\equiv(1)^9( 4\cdot117+44)$ (mod$\space 117)\equiv 44$ (mod$\space 117)
$
The answer is $k=44$

Comment: $3\cdot 37=111$

Comment: I believed the poster Michael Cera but after I realized the true $3\cdot39$

Answer (score 0):

Using the totient function, we have $\Phi (13)=12$ and $\Phi (9)=6$. Since $\gcd (2,13)=\gcd (2,9)=1$ we have $1\equiv 2^{12}\pmod {13}$ and $2^{12}\equiv (2^6)^2\equiv 1 \pmod 9$. Since $\gcd (9,13)=1$ this requires $2^{12}\equiv 1\pmod {117}$. Hence $2^{117}=(2^{12})^9 2^9\equiv 2^9 \equiv 44\pmod {117}$.